# Iterating through JSON object to display a public holidays table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to display a table with a list of public holidays. At the moment I have a table row with the holiday name on the left and date on the right.

The data which appears is from the final array of the JSON object only where I want to display all of the public holidays.

html of table:

```
                    <table class="table table-striped" > 
                        <tbody class="summT">
                            <div class="resptext">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="left" id="txtHolidayName">
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="fontGrey" id="txtHolidayDate">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

I have the following code within the success block of the AJAX call to the api:

```
   ............. 

   result.data.response.holidays.forEach(datepoint => {
                              
                            $dateIterate = new Date(datepoint.date.iso);
                            $('#txtHolidayDate').html($dateIterate.toDateString());
                            $('#txtHolidayName').html(datepoint.name);
                            
                          })
```

Any ideas are gratefully appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Maybe instead writing into the same element, making new rows would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are going to need to do is have template HTML within your loop that you populate with each iteration, and then inject each copy of the filled out template into the table HTML:

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped" > 
    <tbody class="summT">
        <div id="holidates" class="resptext">
        </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript loop:

```
result.data.response.holidays.forEach(datepoint => {
    $('#holidates').append('<tr>\n' +
    '<td align="left" >' + datepoint.name + '</td>' +
    '<td class="fontGrey" >' + new Date(datepoint.date.iso).toDateString() + '</td>\n' + 
    '</tr>');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much Will. I really appreciate it.  I can now see a list of the dates :)